# Inserting image inside another image

Tags: php, facebook, image-processing, user-interface

I am developing a Facebook Application,I am trying to Insert images of my top 5 friends inside an other image through Php Code? How can do this I had searched the PhP Draw function but couldn't Find anyone.
Through this Image you may get what I want to do
![enter image description here][1]
I had seen this Function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with the function you've given. However, it doesn't quite work like this. Here's how PHP could handle your situation:

1. [imagecreatefromjpeg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) converts a JPEG image to an internal PHP image format called "resource" (you need to convert both your source image and your profile pic in order for them to be manipulated)
2. [imagecopy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) copies one image onto another (here, the profile pic onto the base image)
3. [imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) writes text on your image, given a font (the scores)
4. Your image is almost done, you only have to convert it from a PHP resource back to a JPEG image with [imagejpeg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Comment: The Algorithm seems to be Working.have You ever tried that?

Comment: @zain Not exactly that, but yes, I have fiddled with the image library in PHP a long time ago. Glad it's working for you!

Comment: OK thanks..Can you give me skype Address of an Faceboo App Developer?Thats Urgent